# OData IQueryable DTO mapping in separate method does not work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I have issues with DTO mapping. I'm using OData WebAPI and I need to use IQueryable due to paging, sorting, filtering...
When I use this code (simplified for this purpose) in my WebAPI controller, it works

```
return Ok(_dataService.GetEntities(idUser).Select(e => new EntityDTO 
{
    ID = e.ID,
    Name = e.Name   
}));
```

but when I have separate method for DTO mapping it does not work.

```
return Ok(_dataService.GetEntities(idUser).Select(e => _dataService.MapToEntityDTO(e)));
```

Methods in my _dataService object (simplified)

```
public IQueryable<Entity> GetEntities(long idUser)
{        
    return from z in _context.Entities select z;
}

public EntityDTO MapToEntityDTO(Entity entity) {
    return new EntityDTO {
            ID = entity.ID,
            Name = entity.Name  
        };
}
```

Could you please someone explain me what is wrong with that ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that GetEntities is returning an `IQueryable` that EF would be deferring execution until the results need to be materialized. This would fail if you try calling some arbitrary C# method (MapToEntity) because EF cannot translate that down into SQL.

What you should consider using is Automapper which contains a method called `ProjectTo` which can integrate with EF's `IQueryable` to project your DTOs through a configured mapper.

```
var dtos = _dataService.GetEntities(idUser)
    .ProjectTo<EntityDTO>(config)
    .ToList();
return Ok(dtos);
```

Where "config" is an instance of the Automapper Configuration class containing the mapping config to convert the Entity(ies) to DTO(s).

The alternative with a custom mapper that doesn't integrate with `IQueryable` is that you would have to materialize the entities first, then perform the mapping in memory:

```
var dtos = _dataService.GetEntities(idUser)
    .ToList() // Materializes the entities
    .Select(e => _dataService.MapToEntityDTO(e))
    .ToList();
return Ok(dtos);
```

The disadvantages of this approach are that it requires more memory and time from the server to load the entities into memory first, then perform the mapping `Select`. This also requires that the GetEntities() method ensures that any/all related entities that might be mapped are eager loaded, otherwise they would either trigger lazy loads or be left #null. This can blow out time and memory usage where little of this related data might actually be needed.

With the `ProjectTo` projection, the queries will automatically fetch whatever related details are needed without the overhead of needing to eager load relations or tripping lazy loads.